# Where to find `asm/atomic.h` in cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, atomic

I'm currently in Windows environment using cygwin. I'm looking for `asm/atomic.h` to work with atomic integers and operations, but without luck...

Comment: I assume you mean the `asm/atomic.h` header file from the *Linux kernel*? Then you won't find it. However, if your compiler is new enough it might support [the (optional) atomic functions introduced in C11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Comment: So, the answer is nowhere, but use alternative?

Comment: the atomic.h header file can be installed via the 'setup' utility in cygwin or gotten via ftp from: ftp://cygwin.osuosl.org/.2/nslu2/sources/cvs/glibc/libc/.../atomic.h